# Auto execute vim PluginInstall during docker build

Tags: docker, vim, dockerfile

I'm building a docker image and I'd like it to pull down my dotfiles, saved on my github, as well as install the vim plugins I have specified.

```
RUN cd ~ && git clone https://github.com/bdhammel/dotfiles.git && \
    ./dotfiles/makesymlinks.sh && vim +silent! +PluginInstall +qall
```

However, doing so throws this error and kills the build:

```
Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
```

Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Silent Batch Mode

For very simple text processing (i.e. using Vim like an enhanced 'sed' or 'awk', without any interactivity <= this is what prevents the *input/output not from a terminal* error), use *Ex-mode*.

```
vim -T dumb -n -i NONE -es -S "commands.ex"
```

Attention: Vim will hang waiting for input if the `"commands.ex"` file doesn't exist; better check beforehand for its existence! Alternatively, Vim can read the commands from stdin. You can also fill a new buffer with text read from stdin, and read commands from stderr if you use the `-` argument.

To avoid having a separate script with the commands, you can use Bash's *process substitution*:

```
... -S <(echo -e "silent! PluginInstall\nqall")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fully working example I use:

```
RUN [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "vim -T dumb -n -i NONE -es -S <(echo -e 'silent! PluginInstall')" ]
```